# Xcode pass data from a viewcontroller to another viewcontroller in a different storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have two storyboards that contain one view controller each.

storyboard1 --------> viewcontrollerA

storyboard2  --------> viewcontrollerB

How do I pass a string from viewcontrollerA to viewcontrollerB?

Example:

```
viewcontrollerB.testString=@"The transfer of data worked!";
```

So far, I know how to transfer views, but I don't know how to transfer data.

This is my code to transfer views:

```
- (IBAction)moveToViewcontrollerB:(id)sender {

UIStoryboard *storyboard2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard2" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *viewcontrollerB = [storyboard2 instantiateInitialViewController];

viewcontrollerB.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self presentViewController:lessonOne_ViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

My question is, if I have a string in viewcontrollerB called "testString", how do I update that string in the viewcontrollerA IBaction method?

I only know how to transfer data using segues but since this viewcontroller is on another storyboard, a segue - prepareForSegue won't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: declare a strong type of NSString in ViewControllerB. Then access in ViewControllerA as --> `viewcontrollerB.testString = @"Hello ViewController B";`

Comment: I've tried all of these solutions but none of them work. This thread uses a lot of depreciated methods and none of them can instantiate a viewcontroller correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all set `Storyboard ID` to your `SecondView Controller` like below image.

[image]

Then add following `code` at your `button click` event.

```
- (IBAction)moveToViewcontrollerB:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard2"
                                                         bundle: nil];
    SecondStoryboardVC * secondStoryboardVCOBJ_ = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondClassStoryboardID"];
    [secondStoryboardVCOBJ_ setStrValue:@"The transfer of data worked!"];
    secondStoryboardVCOBJ_.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:secondStoryboardVCOBJ_ animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

`Storyboard2` is `storyboard` name.

`SecondClassStoryboardID` is `Storyboard ID` which you given in `storyboard viewController` like above image.

`SecondStoryboardVC` is the `secondclass` name which you want to `present`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Xcode is giving me an error with this line: SecondStoryboardVC * secondStoryboardVCOBJ_ = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondClassStoryboardID"]; -----> It's saying that "storyboard" is a unknown receiver?

Comment: `SecondStoryboardVC` is the second class name which you want to present.

Please see the updated answer. In your example its `viewcontrollerB`

Comment: @AbhishekSharma What is "setStrValue"?